# Different source IPs when connecting to AWS instances in same AZ

Tags: networking, nat

When connecting to my AWS instances in the same AZ, I am able to connect to some instances and not others even though all instances were using the same NACL an Security Groups.

My security groups were set up to allow all traffic from my IP address which I obtained by running the following on my client machine:

`echo $(curl -s http://ifconfig.me/ip)/32`

To debug the problem, I opened up the SG temporarily to allow access to port 22 from 0.0.0.0/0 and run `tail -f /var/log/secure` on a server I couldn't connect to and attempted to connect from my client machine.

At this point, I noticed that depending on the host I was trying to connect to, I had different source IPs.

I'm using a Fritzbox on Glasfaser:

[image]

Source: https://www.deutsche-glasfaser.de/glasfaser/hausanschluss/

What could cause this?  Is this double NAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that glasfaser are using [Carrier Grade NAT (CGNAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

One workaround is to connect to the instances use IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

If your source IPs are dynamic, you can't use these IPs as a trust source in your ACL/security group.

You should setup a jump-host / bounce-host in you AWS subnet. This server is considered "secure", and you access your instances only from this host.

setup a secure way to autenticate to this jump-host / bounce server. like openvpn or ssh with two factor auth or client certificates, etc

Comment: Thanks @exeral.  Is there a way to find out that source IPs with glasfaser will be dynamic?  I haven't encountered this issue before.

Comment: unfortunately glasfaser website is deutsch only so I can't find the information for you